# Prove $(A \cap B) \cap (A \setminus B) = \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm asked to prove that $(A \cap B) \cap (A \setminus B) = \emptyset$.  This is equivalent to showing $(A \cap B) \cap (A \setminus B) \subset \emptyset$ and $\emptyset \subset  (A \cap B) \cap (A \setminus B)$ .

Since the empty set is a subset of every set, then all we need to show is $(A \cap B) \cap (A \setminus B) \subset \emptyset$.

Let $x \in (A \cap B) \cap (A \setminus B).$ This is equivalent to

$$ \iff x \in A \land x\in B \land x \in A \land x \not\in B $$

$$ \iff x \in A \land x\in B \land x \not\in B $$

Since logical statements associate, then

$$ \iff x \in A \land (x\in B \land x \not\in B)$$

which is always false by the law of excluded middle ( $p \land \neg p$ is always false). Since no such element can satisfy this statement, and since $x$ was arbitrary, then no such $x$ exists and hence the set is empty.

How is my logic there?  I'm mostly concerned with the bit about law of excluded middle and less about the beginning and middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is fine. In fact, using basic properties about set operations (assuming that you've proved them), you can streamline the argument:
$$
(A \cap B) \cap (A \setminus B) 
= (A \cap B) \cap (A \cap B^{\mathrm{c}}) 
= (A \cap A) \cap (B \cap B^{\mathrm{c}}) 
= A \cap \varnothing 
= \varnothing
$$

Comment: This of course requires complements to be defined with respect to a suitable set, rather than the universe; in this case, $A\cup B$ will do.